# Ajax to WCF, can't load Ajax into an object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

I want to send some data back form my JavaScript to WCF. This object I send back needs to get loaded in the Foo class. If I debug the code I can see the function (Sting) gets called. But if i check whats in the the object I got returned, this object is null.

This indicates the data can't be stored in in the Object of WCF. The WCF works find when I send data to the JavaScript with Ajax. FYI I use .NET 3.5

this is how I try to receive the data: WCF:

```
namespace TPlatform
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class DataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public void Sting(Foo postData)
        {
            var x = 1; //Breakpoint, postData is null?
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Foo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Bar;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var fooObject = { "Bar": "test" };
function sendDataToWcf(object) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DataService.svc/Sting",
        data: JSON.stringify(fooObject),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: suckcess,
        error: showError
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I read the the data into my class?

Comment: Is your WCF service a restful service ?

Comment: Have you tried to change datatype to jsonp in the ajax call. If not i think you ahve to enable ajax in your wcf service.

Comment: Well now I get an error but its still null. Now I get an parsererror. Good comment!

Comment: No, Luck! :(   and I still get the success message...

Comment: plz look at my new updated answer

Comment: Without the "" the object is still null

Comment: Is it null on the client side or server side ?

Comment: Ok. can you turn on wcf tracing and diagnostics in the server. Then read the data what does it says

Comment: I jsut edited can you try that. If not you ahve to look at the trace data and begin troubleshooting from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            //dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ postData: fooObject}),
            success: function (response) {
                successCallback(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                handleError(xhr, status, error);
            }
        });
```

Update: Change:

```
var fooObject = { "Bar": "test" };
```

too

```
var fooObject = { Bar: "test" };
```

and dont send the datatype.